# How to cancel group of previous actions in Elasticsearch? Transactional approach

Tags: elasticsearch

I use Elasticsearch for e-commerce (goods storing instead of DB). When somebody forms order, goods are being placed in reserve. In mapping I have field 'reserved'. I need to increase this number for every goods in order (using version). But if one of goods in order had been already reserved or out of stock I need to cancel all previous increments of field 'reserved' for all of goods in the order. What is the best practice to do it? In Mysql I can use transactions. Elasticsearch has no transactions support.

Comment: probably, you should have a list of changes and revert those changes with your program

Comment: This is the most obvious variant, but... What if... There are two buyers. 1st added to cart Goods1, placed his order and while system checks for availability of other goods from his cart, somebody asses Goods1 to his cart too and placed order too. 2nd user will get message that goods out of stock. Then 1st user get a message that one of some other goods is out of stock and system cancel his order. 1st user changes his mind and do not buy all goods becaouse of one which is absent. And second user think that Goods1 is out of stock, although Goods1 is already in stock.